# trying to make an raycast, getting error "called expresion before int"

Tags: c

the error is saying "expected expression before 'int'" and "called object 'my' is not a function"
im following a tutorial on how to make my own game with raycast engine

```
int r, mx, my, mp, dof; float rx, ry, ra, xo, yo;
    ra = pa;
    for (r = 0; r < 1; r++)
    {
        dof = 0;
        float aTan =- 1 / tan(ra);
        if(ra > PI) { ry = (((int)py>>6)<<6)-0.0001; rx = (py - ry) * aTan + px; yo =- 64; xo = -yo *aTan; }
        if(ra < PI) { ry = (((int)py>>6)<<6)+64; rx = (py - ry) * aTan + px; yo = 64; xo = -yo *aTan; }
        if(ra == 0 || ra == PI) { rx = px; ry = py; dof = 8; }
        while(dof < 8)
        {
            mx = (int)(rx)>>6; my(int)(ry)>>6; mp = my * mapX + mx;
            if (mp < mapX && map[mp] == 1) { dof = 8; }
            else { rx += xo; ry += yo; dof += 1; }
        }
        
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
        glLineWidth(1);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(px, py);
        glVertex2i(rx, ry);
        glEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Well what is `my(int)(ry)` supposed to do?

Comment: it was in the tutorial

Comment: Bad tutorial, use a good book instead to learn C.

Comment: i still need solution

Comment: Then tell us what its supposed to do, we dont know what that piexe of code is supposed to be

Comment: Did you maybe mean `my = (int)(ry)>>6 `? Your question is very unclear and without further info we can not help.

Comment: yeah the error would go away but then raycast wouldnt be visible

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to compile a C function, but the you code does not comply with the language.

If you are using the code as listed above, you need an outer function definition.

Add something like
void myFunc(){
at the top
and a close brace '}' at the end.

If this is an exercise to introduce you into code you may want to consider a less mathematically interesting example.